# "Table of Figures" Title and "Table of Codes" Title not in the same line

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

[image]

Hello! I have the following problem: the title of my table of listings (codes) is not in the same  position as the title of my table of figures is. You can see the 2 pages of the tables in the pic.

I have tried some things, but I didn't managed to place the title of the table of listings like the one of the table of figures.

My code for adding the tables is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\geometry{
a4paper,
left=30mm,
right=30mm,
top=30mm,
bottom=30mm,
}

\begin{document}

% list of figures (correct)
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\doublespacing
\listoffigures
\singlespacing

\newpage

% list of listings (title not in the correct position)
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
\doublespacing
\lstlistoflistings 
\singlespacing

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? I would appreciate it if someone could help me, as I have been facing this problem for a long time. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not only post code snippets, but make it compilable, i.e. complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The strange fiddling with `\doublespacing` etc. is weird

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have edited my code, it is too simple. Only the table of figures and the table of codes.  If you compile it and see the vertical positions of the two titles of tables you will notice the problem. I want them both to have the vertical position of the table of figures. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @crixstox I have edited my code, it is too simple :)

Comment: @GreekFreak On this site, adding “SOLVED” is not used. Just assign the green tick to the answer that most helped you in solving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift the loading of `float` after `listings`, this will cure the problem. The reason is the `float@listhead` setting provided by `float` package. If the package is loaded after `listings`, `listings` uses a different setup for `\lstlistoflistings`, especially the spacings are quite standard then.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb} 

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=30mm,
  right=30mm,
  top=30mm,
bottom=30mm,
}

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
% list of figures (correct)
\phantomsection
\doublespacing
\listoffigures
\hrule
\singlespacing

\clearpage

% list of listings (title not in the correct position)
\phantomsection
\doublespacing
\lstlistoflistings 
\hrule
\singlespacing
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

[image]